# Adding pages to the side navigation in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, navigation

I'm currently creating a site using Sharepoint, I notice when I add a page into the root it automatically adds them onto the top navigation, but I'd like to have a side navigation too (with sub pages)

Unfortunately this is quite different to any project I've worked on before, and find when compared to other CMS it is very tricky to find much information online about how to perform relatively simple tasks in Sharepoint, so I'd really appreciate any help!

Thank you

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. You might interested in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah that is fantastic, thank you! Will no doubt prove very useful... should I re-post this question there, or is it okay here for now? Apologies

Answer (score 2):

Check that your pages are published and approved

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, are you creating Web Part Pages? These pages by default have the left navigation hidden, you should use publishing pages instead (Create Page from Site Actions, and not New Web Part Page from Create)

Answer (score 1):

You did not state the version of SharePoint you are using, so this explanation is for SP2010:

- Go to Site Settings --> Navigation

There you can add/remove pages to the "global navigation" (that would be the top navigation) and the "current navigation" (that would be the side).

Comment: Ah, this is great, thank you - unfortunately this was already selected and correct, and on 3 of my pages it shows the left navigation, but on the other two it doesn't - despite them all running the same theme supposedly! ;o

Comment: Also, it shows the same pages on the top navigation as it does on the side... ideally I'd like entirely different things, but I guess that's not possible?

Comment: In the same menu (Navigation) you can select to show "the same pages as the global navigation" or e.g. "only pages from the current website". In the bottom you can sort and add new links to the current navigation.